# Dispatching thunk action creator does not match in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-thunk

I'm trying to create an async action with [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk). It almost works but the only problem is `dispatch(f())` causes error in TSC.

As reading [redux official document](https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions#indexjs), it accepts functions.

The code is here:

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore, Reducer } from 'redux';
import thunkMiddleware, { ThunkAction } from 'redux-thunk';

// --------------------------------
// State

export interface IAppState {
  active: boolean;
}
const initialAppState: IAppState = {
  active: false,
};

// --------------------------------
// Actions and action creators

type AppAction = { type: 'turnOn' } | { type: 'turnOff' };

function turnOn (): AppAction {
  return { type: 'turnOn' };
}

function turnOff (): AppAction {
  return { type: 'turnOff' };
}

// --------------------------------
// Reducers

const rootReducer: Reducer<IAppState, AppAction> = (
  state = initialAppState,
  action,
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'turnOn': return { ...state, active: true };
    case 'turnOff': return { ...state, active: false };
    default: return state;
  }
};

// --------------------------------
// Store

export function createAppStore () {
  return createStore<IAppState, AppAction, {}, {}>(
    rootReducer,
    applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware),
  );
}

const store = createAppStore();

// --------------------------------
// Use store

store.dispatch(turnOn());
store.dispatch(turnOff());

// --------------------------------
// Thunk action

function turnOnAndOff (
  delay: number,
): ThunkAction<Promise<void>, IAppState, null, AppAction> {
  return (dispatch) => new Promise((resolve) => {
    dispatch(turnOn());
    setTimeout(() => {
      dispatch(turnOff());
      resolve();
    }, delay);
  });
}

store.dispatch(turnOnAndOff(1000)); // ERROR
```

In the last line, TSC says their types do not match.

> TypeScript error: Argument of type 'ThunkAction< Promise< void>, IAppState, null, AppAction>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AppAction'.
>     Property 'type' is missing in type 'ThunkAction< Promise< void>, IAppState, null, AppAction>' but required in type '{ type: "turnOff"; }'.  TS2345

If I wrote `turnOnAndOff(1000) as any` instead, it works correctly.

How to let `dispatch()` accept the function?

Answer (score 4):

Dispatching thunk actions using store.dispatch is not supported by the current redux-thunk typings.  Usually you would have a mapDispatchToProps where you could type the dispatch as ThunkDispatch.  You can do an inline cast even though it is ugly and casting loses type-safety.  See this answer: [How to dispatch an Action or a ThunkAction (in TypeScript, with redux-thunk)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43013204/how-to-dispatch-an-action-or-a-thunkaction-in-typescript-with-redux-thunk#answer-50741539)

Comment: OK I understand it is not possible for now. Object style `mapDispatchToProps` at `connect()` works then. Thanks!

Comment: I just started learning Typescript and this is really a major step back for me. This makes me sad.