# Dispatching a Redux Thunk action outside of a React component with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-thunk

I'm in the process of converting a React Native app into TypeScript and I'm having trouble with dispatching thunk actions outside of the store. Here is how my store is set up currently:

**store/index.ts**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers, Reducer, Store } from 'redux';
import thunk, { ThunkMiddleware } from 'redux-thunk';

export interface State { ... }
export interface ActionTypes { ... } // All of the non-thunk actions

const reducer: Reducer<State> = combineReducers({ ... });

export default (): Store<State> => {
  return applyMiddleware(
    thunk as ThunkMiddleware<State, ActionTypes>
  )(createStore)(reducer);
}
```

**index.tsx**

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import createStore from './store/index';
import { registerStore } from './store/registry'; 

const store = createStore();

registerStore(); // Registers the store in store/registry.ts

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
));
```

**store/registry.ts**

```
import { Store } from 'redux';
import { State } from './index';

let store: Store<State>;

export const registerStore = (newStore: Store<State>) => {
  store = newStore;
};

export const getStore = () => store;
```

So when the store is created, I'm storing it in the store registry so I can call `getStore()` from anywhere.

---

This works fine in components (where I'm not using the registry), for example in my **App.tsx**:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { ThunkDispatch } from 'redux-thunk';
import { checkAuthStatus as checkAuthStatusAction } from './store/modules/auth/actions';
import { ActionTypes, State as AppState } from './store/index';

interface State = { ... }
interface StateProps { ... }
interface DispatchProps {
  checkAuthStatus: () => Promise<boolean>;
}
type Props = StateProps & DispatchProps;

class App extends Component<Props, State> {
  async componentDidMount() {
    const promptSkipped: boolean = await checkAuthStatus(); // Thunk action, works fine!
  }
  ...
}

const mapStateToProps = ...;
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: ThunkDispatch<AppState, null, ActionTypes>): DispatchProps => ({
  checkAuthStatus: () => dispatch(checkAuthStatusAction()),
});

export default connect<StateProps, DispatchProps, {}, AppState>(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(App);
```

---

The problem comes when I want to use the registry to dispatch a thunk action:

**lib/notacomponent.ts**

```
import { getStore } from '../store/registry';
import { checkAuthStatus, setLoggedIn } from '../store/modules/auth/actions'

const someFunction = () => {
  const store = getStore();

  const { auth } = store.getState(); // Accessing state works fine!

  store.dispatch(setLoggedIn(true)); // NON-thunk action, works fine!

  store.dispatch(checkAuthStatus()); // Uh-oh, thunk action doesn't work.
}
```

This gives me the error:

```
Argument of type 'ThunkAction<Promise<boolean>, State, null, Action<any>>' is 
not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'.

Property 'type' is missing in type 'ThunkAction<Promise<boolean>, State, null, Action<any>>'
but required in type 'AnyAction'. ts(2345)
```

As far as I am aware, using `thunk as ThunkMiddleware<State, ActionTypes>` as a middleware allows Redux Thunk to replace the stores dispatch method with one that makes it possible to dispatch thunk actions *and* normal actions.

I think I need to somehow type the registry in a way that TypeScript can see that the dispatch method is *not* the default one that only allows normal actions. I am, however, at a loss on how to do this. I can't find any examples of anyone else doing the same thing.

Any help is appreciated.

---

**Edit**: The suggested duplicate of [How to dispatch an Action or a ThunkAction (in TypeScript, with redux-thunk)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43013204)
 doesn't solve my issue. I can dispatch thunk actions fine inside components. I'm only having issues outside components, using the store registry defined above.

---

**Edit 2**: So it seems I can use the following type assertion when dispatching the thunk action to get rid of the error:

```
(store.dispatch as ThunkDispatch<State, void, ActionTypes>)(checkAuthStatus())
```

That is very impractical though. I'm yet to find a way to make it so TypeScript knows that the `dispatch` method should always be able to dispatch a thunk action.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to dispatch an Action or a ThunkAction (in TypeScript, with redux-thunk)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43013204/how-to-dispatch-an-action-or-a-thunkaction-in-typescript-with-redux-thunk)

Comment: found that topic after looking through redux github's issues(https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk/issues/135 - looks identically to your case)

Comment: @skyboyer I don't think that helps unfortunately. It's working fine inside a component. I tried adding `(store.dispatch as ThunkDispatch<State, void, ActionTypes>)` as in pierpytom's answer but that didn't change anything.

Comment: hm, it's strange. so complete call looks like `(store.dispatch as ThunkDispatch<State, void, ActionTypes>)(checkAuthStatus())` and that gives the same error about lucking `type` property, right? if yes, how about force type casting to something like `(...args: any[]) => any`?

Comment: @skyboyer Actually, `(store.dispatch as ThunkDispatch<State, null, ActionTypes>)(checkAuthStatus())` does work. I didn't change the second argument of `ThunkDispatch` to `null` the first time. Is there something I can do with the store registry to make that always the case? It's a bit hacky to be doing that for every thunk action

Comment: don't know, sorry. did you checked https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk/blob/master/test/typescript.ts ? may help on typing thunk actions

Comment: @skyboyer Yeah I've seen that, it's what I referred to when setting up the store. Thanks though

Comment: may  I create small sandbox to play with?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is almost correct. You incorrectly set return type of your default export.

```
export default (): Store<State> => {
    return applyMiddleware(
        thunk as ThunkMiddleware<State, ActionTypes>
    )(createStore)(reducer);
}
```

In case of middleware usage, function above should return not `Store<State>`, but `Store<S & StateExt, A> & Ext` where `Ext` will be overloaded `dispatch` which will be able to dispatch [functions](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk/blob/0e60b6264fb402afb328157c4337f5cc87a07b53/index.d.ts#L20) (as redux-thunk do).

To simplify, just remove exact return type and let TypeScript infer type itself

```
export default () => {
    return applyMiddleware(
        thunk as ThunkMiddleware<State, ActionTypes>
    )(createStore)(reducer);
}
```

Thats solve your problem.

Alternatively, you may use more classical approach to store creation.

```
export default () => {
    return createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunk as ThunkMiddleware<State, ActionTypes>));
}
```

Essential things here:

1. Use `createStore` as recommended by [Redux official doc](https://redux.js.org/api/createstore). `createStore` called with middleware as second argument will itself [call it](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/cf749356db98b1dfd8ad089e6899cd5d9eeb0aae/src/createStore.js#L53). But TypeScript declaration files for redux and redux-thunk are preconfigured for such use of `createStore`. So returned store will have [modified version](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/cf749356db98b1dfd8ad089e6899cd5d9eeb0aae/index.d.ts#L266) of `dispatch`. (Make note of `Ext and StateExt` type parameters of `StoreEnhancer<Ext, StateExt>`. They will be intersected with resulting store and add overloaded version of `dispatch` which will accepts functions as arguments).
2. Also return type of default exported fucntion will be inferred from `createStore`'s return type. It will NOT be `Store<State>`.

Comment: Removing the `Store<State>` from the export didn't fix the issue itself (I'd tried removing it already), as `store` was still inferred as `any` by TypeScript inside `store/registry`. *But*, switching to the 'classical approach' of creating the store allowed me to see in VSCode exactly what type was being returned, which for some reason I couldn't with the original method. So now I've typed `store` as ```Store<State, ActionTypes> & { dispatch: `ThunkDispatch<State, undefined, ActionTypes>` }```. Not sure if that's the best approach but it's solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
const boundActions = bindActionCreators( { checkAuthStatus }, store.dispatch);
boundActions.checkAuthStatus();
```

This works and does not look as hacky as 'Edit2'